# SearchView в Android

Tags: java, android, searchview

Есть проблема, связанная с элементом SearchView. Когда я нажимаю на иконку лупы, то SearchView не сразу переходит в режим ввода текста. Сначала иконка уезжает влево, а вот если опять ее нажать, то ввод текста активируется. [image: Так выглядит SearchView если ничего не делать]

Теперь когда я нажал на иконку лупы

[image: Лупа уезжает влево]

А теперь, что бы появилось поле ввода текста, мне приходится еще раз нажать на иконку лупы.

[image: Только тогда появляется поле ввода текста]

Не понимаю почему это происходит. 
Код меню с SearchView:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Поиск"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

Код в MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_item);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: На сколько я помню, нужен еще `SearchManager`.